# Stream Python JSON data into PySpark Dataframe with column header

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I use structured stream from Kafka Source into PySpark Dataframe. The data types which Kafka provide is JSON with structure like this:

```
{
"id":XXX,
"user_id":1,
"status":"PENDING",
...,
}
```

which I want to stream it, with the output that the key of JSON is the table header:

```
--------------------
id |user_id|status |
--------------------
XXX|1      |PENDING|
```

I try with this code:

```
schema = = StructType() \
    .add("id", IntegerType()) \
    .add("user_id", IntegerType()) \
    .add("status", StringType())

src = spark.readStream\
    .format("kafka")\
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",KAFKA_SERVER)\
    .option("subscribe",KAFKA_TOPIC)\
    .option("startingOffsets","earliest")\
    .load()
    FDR = src.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"),schema).alias("parsed"))
    query = FDR.writeStream\
        .format("console")\
        .option("truncate", False)\
        .start()
```

But nothing out and it stop without show anything. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after several research, I take a wrong select query. It must be like this:

```
.select(
       from_json(col("value").cast("string"),<your_schema>).alias("<your_alias>")
    )
    FDR.select("<your_alias>.*")
```